# Unattended install of Ubuntu server - grub-install asking for confirmation

Tags: 14.04, grub2, system-installation, preseed

I am trying to perform an automated install of customized Ubuntu server 14.04. Everything is working fine, except one annoying grub confirmation message:

[image]

Preseed file:

```
d-i preseed/early_command string umount /media
d-i debconf/priority string critical
d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition \
select Finish partitioning and write changes to disk
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true
d-i grub-installer/bootdev string /dev/sda
d-i preseed/late_command string cp /cdrom/install/grub.sh /target/root; chroot /target chmod +x /root/grub.sh; chroot /target bash /root/grub.sh ; rm -f /target/root/grub.sh
```

I am also using kickstart in combination with the preseed:

```
lang en_US
langsupport en_US
keyboard us
mouse
timezone Asia/Tokyo
rootpw --disabled
user ubuntu --fullname "ubuntu" --iscrypted --password xxx
reboot
text
install
cdrom
bootloader --location=mbr 
zerombr yes
clearpart --all --initlabel 
auth  --useshadow  --enablemd5 
firewall --enabled 
skipx
```

Why the installer is complaining about "not choosing any device to install" even though the preseed file has the device mentioned?. How to get rid of the grub install confirm message?. I think the issue is related to the preseed.

Comment: If you're trying to install in a GPT drive then `--location=mbr` won't be found.

Comment: the disk is a qcow2 virtual machine disk

Comment: Here it's mentioned the target as `/dev/nbd0` : http://diogogomes.com/2012/07/13/debootstrap-kvm-image/index.html

Comment: The same here: http://tic-le-polard.blogspot.com.es/2015/04/qemu-create-complete-system-image.html Apparently you need to adjust for this type of virtual disks whereas you're trying to apply a procedure valid only for "msdos" (MBR) drives.

Comment: the device is /dev/sda only. I inspected using shell while installing

Comment: I am also suspecting the kickstart file. Anything to be removed /added regarding bootloader?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this things, far from it. I just go by the error message about no being able to install Grub and the few things I've found regarding the type of virtual drives you're using (links above).